# How to get native HMODULE for .NET assembly (class library)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I want to use native API, which can accept `HMODULE` as input parameter.
Is there any way to get `HMODULE` for executing assembly?
I'm aware of [`Module.ModuleHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.module.modulehandle?view=net-5.0) and have no idea how to convert `ModuleHandle` to `HMODULE`.

Something like this:

```
// convert somehow
var hModule = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.ModuleHandle;

// call native API
```

This is Windows platform-dependent code, so, it's OK to use specific platform APIs if required.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, ha, so simple. Thanks, it works. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .NET assemblies are also regular Windows DLLs you should be able to call the native function GetModuleHandle(). You can see from the output of a debug run what the module names are, if that's not obvious.